# Using count() in SQL Server 

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

Here is the piece of code which I use to get the count from column `nos`.

```
//get max count of orders on server .2
    public int getmaxcountfornos(string caseno,TextBox TextBox3)
    {
        int count2 = 0;
        try
        {
            String dd_webCofig = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["counton140"].ConnectionString;
            OdbcConnection ddlistconn = new OdbcConnection(dd_webCofig);
            ddlistconn.Open();

            string cnt_2 = "select count(nos) from training_jud.orders where fil_no=@b and jdate=@c";
            OdbcCommand ddlistCmd_2 = new OdbcCommand(cnt_2, ddlistconn);

            ddlistCmd_2.Parameters.AddWithValue("b", caseno);
            ddlistCmd_2.Parameters.AddWithValue("c", Convert.ToDateTime(TextBox3.Text).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"));

            count2 = (int)ddlistCmd_2.ExecuteScalar();
        }

        catch (Exception ee)
        {
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(ee.Message);
        }
        return count2;
    }
```

Here I am getting the exception as

> Specified cast is not valid.

Can anyone help me sort out this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
//get max count of orders on server .2
public int getmaxcountfornos(string caseno,TextBox TextBox3)
{
    int count2 = 0;
    try
    {
        String dd_webCofig = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["counton140"].ConnectionString;
        OdbcConnection ddlistconn = new OdbcConnection(dd_webCofig);
        ddlistconn.Open();

        string cnt_2 = "select count(nos) from training_jud.orders where fil_no=@b and jdate=@c";
        OdbcCommand ddlistCmd_2 = new OdbcCommand(cnt_2, ddlistconn);

        ddlistCmd_2.Parameters.AddWithValue("**@b**", caseno);
        ddlistCmd_2.Parameters.AddWithValue("**@c**", Convert.ToDateTime(TextBox3.Text).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"));

        count2 = **Convert.ToInt32**(ddlistCmd_2.ExecuteScalar());
    }

    catch (Exception ee)
    {
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(ee.Message);
    }
    return count2;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
count2 = int.Parse(ddlistCmd_2.ExecuteScalar().ToString());
```

using the above instead of

```
count2 = (int)ddlistCmd_2.ExecuteScalar();
```

Solved the problem.

Comment: Probably because the result of `ExecuteScalar` is not an int. It might  be a long, or a uint. The cast won't work in that case. Going via a string (don't do that) works around the problem. Find out what type is actually returned from executing your query.

Answer (score 0):

So far your code is going good, however would you please try with below code part, thanks

```
string cnt_2 = "select count(nos) as OrderCount from training_jud.orders where fil_no=@b and jdate=@c";
OdbcCommand ddlistCmd_2 = new OdbcCommand(cnt_2, ddlistconn);

ddlistCmd_2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@b", caseno);
ddlistCmd_2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@c", Convert.ToDateTime(TextBox3.Text).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"));

count2 = Convert.ToInt32(ddlistCmd_2.ExecuteScalar());
```